# Product Collection: Exclude products from a certain category

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

*$parent_category* has N child categories. How can I get all the products from *$parent_category* EXCEPT the ones that belong to *$excluded_child_category*?

Here's how I retrieve the parent category:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel( 'catalog/category' )->load( $parent_category_id )->getProductCollection();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try something like this

```
Mage::getModel( 'catalog/category' )->load( $parent_category_id )->getProductCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('nin' => array('your category id')));
```

Comment: Have you tried this? Doesn't seem to work for me, throws an error: `Fatal error: Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 816`

Comment: have your flat category is enabled?

Comment: i have change my code , i have not try this out and error you are getting is because of there is no such attribute like 'category_id' so i have changed condition